# Bitcoin sent from unsyncronised (2013) Bitcoin-Qt wallet to Multibit wallet have not arrived

Tags: transactions

The situation: I recently turned on my rather old Fujitsu notebook where I had/have a Bitcoin Qt wallet intended for storage of Bitcoin only. I realised that the RAM memory/storage space was insufficient to syncronise the wallet, so I sent the 'unsynced' content of that wallet to a multibit wallet on another computer where I have other bitcoins. **The bitcoin sent from my Bitcoin Qt wallet have not arrived**,and unless I add some more memory to my old Fujitsu (difficult I am told), I am not able to reactivate my Bitcoin Qt wallet. Nonetheless, I have backed up the Bitcoin Qt wallet.dat file on an external hard-drive.

My questions: 1) Do I just have to be patient and wait for the transaction to be processed, and/or, 2) is there something I can do with my wallet.dat file such as opening up a Bitcoin Core wallet?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Bitcoin Core GUI (Bitcoin-Qt) to download new blocks, you can start it with the `-maxconnections=0` option; this should allow you to use it on any machine upon which it previously worked.

Once you have it open, go to the transactions screen and find your transaction.  Right-click on it and choose the option "Copy transaction ID":

[image: copy txid]

Then open the built-in console.  Starting from the menu at the top: Help → Debug menu → Console tab

Type in the following:

```
gettransaction <paste>
```

Replace `<paste>` with a paste of the transaction ID (txid) you previously copied.  You can leave the weird `-000` on the end of the txid in Bitcoin Core 0.11.1, but you might have to delete it from earlier versions.  Press return to get the output.

Near the end of the output should be a field label "hex".  Copy the long alphanumeric (hex) string that belongs to it.  This is the raw transaction you created encoded in hex.

Go to a [transaction broadcast](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_broadcasting) form, paste in that string, and submit.  For redundancy, you may want to try doing it again on a different site.  This will ensure your transaction gets broadcast to the network.

Multibit should show that it is receiving an unconfirmed transaction within less than a minute; then you just need to wait for confirmations.

P.S. if you don't understand any of these instructions, you may want to ask in the Bitcoin.StackExchange chatroom to make sure the people there agree that these are safe.  You should always be careful taking advice from strangers on the Internet when it comes to your bitcoins. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David,
I appreciate your taking the time to respond.
I am afraid to say that I am having little luck. If you recall from the background I gave to my question, my old Fujitsu notebook was rapidly running out of sufficient RAM, so I speedily sent my 'unsyncronised bitcoin' to a new multibit wallet. The bitcoin have not arrived.
I have the sending address, the receiving address, and the amount of bitcoin I attempted to send, but at the moment of writing, my old computer is at the technicians as they attempt to add a larger memory so that I can get the Bitcoin-Qt client to start working again and eventually suncronise with the blockchain. Do you think that I may just need to be patient and wait for the bitcoin I sent to be verified, even though the original computer is out of action?
Warm regards,
Rupert